# How to verify an element contains ANY text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I often need to wait for an AJAX call to add text to an element on my pages after they finish loading. I understand how to use WebDriverWait to wait for specific text to be present in the element, but I don't see how to wait until there is ANY text present. I'm trying to avoid a while loop that keeps checking the element's text isn't `== ''`.

Here's what I use to find specific text:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'myElem'), 'foo'))
except TimeoutException:
    raise Exception('Unable to find text in this element after waiting 10 seconds')
```

Is there a way to check for any text or a non-empty string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `By.XPATH` and check if the `text()` is non-empty inside the xpath expression:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myElem" and text() != ""]'))
```

FYI, I'm using [`presence_of_element_located()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=presence_of_element_located#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) here:

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
>   page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

Complete code:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myElem" and text() != ""]')))
except TimeoutException:
    raise Exception('Unable to find text in this element after waiting 10 seconds')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can't seem to get the syntax right for your example. `By.xpath` has to be `By.XPATH` I believe, but I still get a TypeError. Also, what is the significance of 'foo' if I don't care what the text contains?

Comment: @Jesse yeah, `xpath` was a typo - see the updated answer with a complete code. Check if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, just saw your updated answer. It seems like it should work, but it's still timing out for me. Example showing the element has text, and then the WebDriverWait timing out - [http://bpaste.net/show/7kl2xNhrrPNTr443YH1M/](http://bpaste.net/show/7kl2xNhrrPNTr443YH1M/)

Comment: @Jesse I see, `myElem` is not a tag name - it is an `id` attribute value. Correct your xpath: `//*[@id="myElem" and text() != ""]`.

Comment: D'oh, I should've caught that! It works! Interesting how it returns a `WebElement` object where my original example with `text_to_be_present_in_element()` returned `True`.